# How to replace a specific value in a MySQL row if the word is exist?

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

How can I replace a specific value in MySQL if it's exist?

I have a **servers** table in that table I have an **opts** row the row's value is:

*+set net_port 28112 +set rcon_password asd +set fs_game mods/pml220 +set sv_punkbuster 1 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate*

I don't want to update the whole row with update statemet just want to replace the ***+set fs_game mods/pml220*** to **+set fs_game mods/test**

I tried with the REPLACE statement but to be honest I don't really understand what is going on, lol.

```
SELECT opts,
  REPLACE( opts, '+set fs_game mods/pml220', '+set fs_game mods/test' ) as opts
FROM servers
WHERE srvid>2709;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't really understand what is going on` isn't the result as expected ? Do you want to change the stored data or just the retrieved data from the select statement ?

Comment: Nothing happened when i ran that replace statement. I want to change the stored data, but not the whole row.

Comment: use update 

`update servers set 
opts = REPLACE( opts, '+set fs_game mods/pml220', '+set fs_game mods/test' )
WHERE  srvid>2709`

this update all rows with srvid>2709. 
You can add additional condition to where to update only those rows which contains specific substring in opts field

Comment: Thank you. Can you write this as answer? so I can accept.

Comment: @benyo your query works just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cb40293ef4e9373d1221024f4ce8d96

Comment: I don't know what happened. I tried it before posted the question but didn't changed the value for me.